# Leaks in water simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a problem
when i hit final preview
I see leaks outside of the map
idk,maybe i set something wrong
[image]

here is the file:http://jmp.sh/v/kUokSPOqtnQ9RwXbxyOw
I am a noob so don't judge hard ....